# How to calculate the time from point to route in Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

How could I using Google Maps API (in js if possible) compute the the walking time to intercept a route ??

I have found code to compute this geometrically, but I'm looking for something more precise. Currently I'm bearking down the route in streets and computing the time to each street them sorting it and returning the lowest option.

Comment: Is this straight-line distance, or distance following a route? Are you intercepting an arbitrary point on a line between two points of the route , or are you targeting specific points?

Comment: bcdan, Not the distance, I'm looking for the time in route planning. From point A to the path of route B.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Google Maps Directions API (or any other Google API), it is not possible to compute an intercept from a point to a polyline.

An approximation can be achieved by iterating through all the points (each called A) of the the route, and then using the API to find the routes from B to A. However, this approach will take a *lot* of time to gather data for, and will also use too many queries from the query limit to be practical. Thus, some heuristic to determine likely intercepts and *then* test will be needed.

For more information, please Google the Google Maps Directions API.